# How to build SELECT * WHERE using collection of conditions

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, sql-injection

I want to build a SELECT statement using a list of conditions that come from the query string of a REST api.  I wrote this function, but maybe it is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Can someone tell me if this is vulnerable how to fix it?  Perhaps I should use some kind of SQLBuilder package? or is there a way to do it with just dotNet.  I'm using dotNet 4.6.1

```
    string BuildSelect(NameValueCollection query)
    {
        var result = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
        if (query.Count == 0) return result;
        var logic = " WHERE ";
        foreach (string key in query)
            foreach (string v in query.GetValues(key))
            {
                result += logic + key + " = " + v;
                logic = " AND ";
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: yes, vulnerable. do you have fixed number of query string paramaters?

Comment: @Vinit not a fixed number. I want to keep the software general purpose and not hardcode the column names anywhere. we're using ADO instead of EntityFramework for that reason.

Comment: what will happen if I give invalid column name in the query string, if we use the same column in query then it will not run and will throw error. at least you should map query string keys to table column names. then you can use parameterized queries. i will write some sample code as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. You could build your query to use parameters instead (you are simply using an = check only).

Since you know the tablename, that means you also know what the columns (keys) can be. Thus, you could loop your columns, if the collection has that key then add it to the where as a parameterized statement BUT value part is NOT passed as a string, you parse it to the type it should be (or let the backend do the conversion and get error if cannot be converted). In pseudocode:

```
List<string> clauses = new List<string>();
var result = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
foreach( var col in myTable.Columns )
{
   if (query.ContainsKey(col.Name))
   {
        clauses.Add( $"{col.Name} = @{col.Name}";
        string v = query[col.Name];
        command.Parameters.Add( $"@{col.Name}", col.Type).Value = typeParse(v); 
   }
}
if (clauses.Any())
{
   result += " WHERE " + string.Join( " AND ", clauses );
}
return result;
```

HTH

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Although the table name is hardcoded, I would rather not hardcode the column names.  However, you reminded me that I can use `SqlDataAdapter` with query `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1=2` to get the table schema into a dataset.  Then I can iterate over the column names in the schema, and look for any matches in the query (as in your example).  THANKS AGAIN!